# What does this proof of Fermat's little theorem mean for Euler's theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The following proof of Fermat's little theorem is semi-standard: We prove that $a^p-a \equiv 0 \mod p$ by induction on $a.$ For $a = 2,$ we write
$2^p = (1+1)^p = 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i},$ and since each of the binomial coefficients is divisible by $p,$ we are done. Now, $(a+1)^p = a^p + 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i}a^i \equiv a^p + 1 \equiv a+1$ (by induction). Now, suppose we wanted to prove Euler's theorem ($a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n)$. The very first step of the induction seems to tell us something nontrivial about the binomial coefficients, but is there a direct way to see it?

Comment: "semi-standard" is perhaps an understatement: it also seems to be the first proof given by Euler: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/pages/E054.html , while Fermat just states the theorem.

Comment: @MoritzFirsching For almost all of my mathematical life I had only seen the Lagrange's theorem argument, I just found this in the last couple of months. So, to me, the Lagrange's theorem proof is "standard".

Comment: At the very least, you would have to have a version of Euler's theorem for all $a$ rather than the ones coprime to $n$. If you can formulate it, then it is conceivable that some inductive argument would also work.

Comment: @LevBorisov, by "Euler's theorem for all $a$" do you mean *any*  congruence valid for all $a$ that reduces to Fermat's little theorem when $n$ is prime?  Two possibilities are $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{(k,n)} \equiv 0 \bmod n$ for all $a$ and $\sum_{d \mid n} \varphi(n/d)a^d \equiv 0 \bmod n$ for all $a$.

Comment: I think he means something which implies $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$ in case $\gcd(a,n)=1.$ An obvious candidate is $a^{\phi(n)+1} \equiv a \mod n.$ That might be true for $n$ square-free. However when $n=p^2m$ we have $a=pm$ non-zero but $a^k \equiv 0 \mod n.$ for all $k \ge 2.$ It is still interesting to ask about the $\phi(n)+1$ row of Pascal's triangle ($\mod n$ )in the case that $n$ is a square-free non-prime or merely an odd non-prime.

Comment: You need something annoying like $a^{\phi(n) + e(n)} \equiv a^{e(n)} \bmod n$ where $e(n)$ is the largest power of a prime occurring in the prime factorization of $n$. Not very elegant.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no induction, because Euler's theorem isn't true for all values of $a$, only those coprime to $n$.

Alternatively, here is a generalization of Fermat's little theorem where $p$ isn't necessarily prime but where $a$ is arbitrary: it is the congruence

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \varphi \left( \frac{n}{d} \right) a^d \equiv 0 \bmod n.$$

I don't know a name for this congruence which is in widespread use; I call it the necklace congruence. (Actually there are two necklace congruences; the other one involves $\mu \left( \frac{n}{d} \right)$.)

The proof is very short: you can show using Burnside's lemma that the LHS, divided by $n$, counts the number of orbits of size $n$ of the action of the cyclic group $C_n$ on the set of necklaces of length $n$ with $a$ colors. When $n$ is prime this gives a more direct combinatorial proof of Fermat's little theorem than the one you describe, which amounts to counting necklaces in a more laborious way.

Replacing $a$ with $a + 1$ gives

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \varphi \left( \frac{n}{d} \right) \sum_{i=0}^d {d \choose i} a^i \equiv 0 \bmod n$$

but we can't conclude anything about the coefficients of this thing as a polynomial in $a$ because it's no longer true that the values $\bmod n$ of a polynomial of degree $\le n$ mostly determine its coefficients. (When $p$ is prime this is true except for the leading term.)

A more natural way to get binomial coefficients into the game is to break up the count of necklaces by how many beads of each color there are. You can show, using for example the [Polya enumeration theorem](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/gila-v-the-polya-enumeration-theorem-and-applications/), that this gives the congruence

$$\sum_{d \mid n} \varphi \left( \frac{n}{d} \right) (r_1^{n/d} + \dots + r_a^{n/d})^d \equiv 0 \bmod n$$

where the $r_i$ are actually indeterminates this time; the power of $r_i$ counts how many times the $i^{th}$ color appears. As a statement about number-theoretic properties of the binomial coefficients, this appears to be related to [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), although a more direct proof is possible along these lines: see, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/the-p-group-fixed-point-theorem/).